# Moving rows based on column value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet, and if the data in column B matches a certain value, I want to cut and insert that entire row up to the top of the spreadsheet.

This is what I have so far:

```
Cells.Find("TRCH").Select
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Select
Selection.Cut
Range("7:7").Select
Selection.Insert
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

This code works, but it only finds the first instance of TRCH.  What do I need to change so that all rows containing TRCH will be inserted starting at row 7?

Thanks in advance!

I've updated with screenshots.  The first example is the original set of data.  The second example is what I want it to look like after I run my macro.  The code above only moves the first row with TRCH to the top.  Hope that clarifies.

[image: original data]

[image: updated data]

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of what you want to happen? Use dummy data and upload the screenshot somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

This hasn't been tested, any problems or questions with the code then let me know:

```
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long

Set wks = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

'loop through each row from 1 to the last row in used range
For lRow = 1 To wks.UsedRange.Rows.Count  

If UCase(wks.Cells(lRow, 2)) = "TRDM" Then 'check if the this cell contains TRDM

    'if there is a match then cut current row and insert into row 7
    wks.Rows(lRow).Cut wks.Range("7:7")

End If

Next
```